# Need help in rephraseing two lines of code because.eregi_replace is depricated

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, eregi, ereg

So I purchased a script package which is using `eregi_replace` and I do not know how to re-write the code to play with `preg_replace()`

> The error is: Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in /home2/leemonster/scripttk.com/helpDesk/inc/header.php on line 19

The code is:

```
if (isset($theme_dir)) 
    $temp = preg_replace('/( href=")([^>]*?eticket\.css")/is', '$1' . $theme_dir . '$2', $temp);

if (isset($page)) 
    $temp = str_replace('admin.php', $page, $temp);
if (isset($page)) 
    $temp = str_replace('index.php', $page, $temp);

$header = eregi_replace($bodytag . '.*', '', $temp);
$footer = eregi_replace('.*' . $bodytag, '', $temp);
```

Comment: What does `$bodytag` contain?

Comment: I am assuming $bodytag contains part of the html to the theme $bodytag = '%%BODY%%'; I'm not sure what else could be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$header = preg_replace('/' . $bodytag . '.*/i', '', $temp);
$footer = preg_replace('/.*' . $bodytag . '/i', '', $temp);
```

I've added a [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), `/` in this case (can be other characters too), that needs to surround all `preg` regular expressions, as well as the `i` flag that makes the match case-insensitive. Just make sure that `$bodytag` doesn't contain said delimiters unescaped.

I'd recommend you read up on how the `preg` suite works, [here's](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was spot on. I will take your advise and read up on the subject.